# How to return a well defined section of memory? for instance a color value of a pixel from image data

Tags: c++, templates, image-processing

I need to perform some manipulation on images. The images can be color/greyscale and 8-bit/16-bit. I want to do it without using any third party library (opencv, IPP etc).

I have:

- The image data as void *.
- Width and height of the image.
- Number of channels
- Bit Resolution of each color channel.

I was thinking of having following structures to represent Color and Image.

***Color structure***

```
template<typename ColorDataType, std::size_t channelCount = 3, std::size_t bitResolution = 8>
struct Color
{
    using DataType = ColorDataType;
    std::array<DataType, channelCount> colorData;
};
```

***Image structure***

```
template<typename ColorType>
class Image
{
    std::size_t width;
    std::size_t height;
    ColorType::DataType * data; // Or a unique_ptr<DataType[]> haven't decided on the ownership yet.

public:
    Image(std::size_t inWidth, std::size_t inHeight, ColorType::DataType * inData)
    :   width(inWidth), height(inHeight), data(inData)
    {}

    Color & GetColor(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
    {
        // How can I return a color element here that could be manipulated from the receiving side?
        // The change should be reflected in the memory addressed by data pointer.
    }
};
```

What would be the best way to return a section of the image data so that I can manipulate it later? I would also like to have a const mechanism for the same, in case my Image is const.

**Additional information:**
The requirement is more about treating the given data stream as a 3-D matrix whose dimensions are:

1. Row of the image
2. Column of the image
3. Color of the image

The 3rd dimension, Color, can have 1 or 3 elements depending on whether the image is a gray-scale image or RGB image. I would like to have a way to access the Color element of an image based on the row and column provided and be able to edit the real data in the data stream based on the Color element received.

By doing so, I was hoping to represent Color as a separate entity, so that I can say "Color has a DataType, channelCount and bitResolution" And Image is made of a particular Color Type

Comment: Are you asking how to access a 1d array as if it were a 2d array?

Comment: @NathanOliver. No, I want to access elements of a 1-D array as if it was a different Type. I might have an array of unsigned char representing rgb values of an image. I want to access it as a color element (with rgb). The data can also be an array of word datatype. In which case the color element will have 3 word elements (for r,g and b)

Comment: And the color can also be a single channel one.
The question was, how can I create such a color element from the image data, that could actually manipulate the real image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `Color` class knows everything about itself to be constructable just from a pointer to your memory. In order for it to actually manipulate your image, pass iterators into `data` to the constructor of `Color` and store these iterators. Every time you manipulate your color object, make sure (beware thread-safety!) to also manipulate the data behind the iterators.

If you don't want to force your receiver to accept references, you can also return [`decltype(auto)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) from GetColor.

I used something similar in a 2D-array class that I wanted to have something similar to a `operator[][]`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class Matrix {

  std::vector<T> _matrix;
  const int _rows;
  const int _cols;

public:
  Matrix(int rows, int cols, T def) : _matrix(rows * cols, def), _rows(rows), _cols(cols) {}
  Matrix(int rows, int cols) : Matrix(rows, cols, T()) {}

  class Row {
  private:
    Matrix<T> &_m;
    const int _row;

  public:
    Row(Matrix<T> &m, int row) : _m(m), _row(row) {}

    decltype(auto) operator[](int col) {
      assert(col >= 0);
      assert(col < _m.cols());
      return _m._matrix[_row * _m.cols() + col];
    }
  };
  friend class Row;

  Row operator[](int row) {
    assert(row >= 0);
    assert(row < _rows);
    return Row(*this, row);
  }

  int rows() const { return _rows; }
  int cols() const { return _cols; }
};
```

*EDIT:* This should be more like what you are looking for:

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <std::size_t channelCount = 3, std::size_t bitResolution = 8> struct Color {
private:
  std::vector<int>::iterator begin;

public:
  Color(std::vector<int>::iterator begin) : begin(begin) {}

  std::string toString() const {
    std::string rep = "(";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < channelCount; ++i) {
      rep += std::to_string(*(begin + i));
      if (i + 1 < channelCount)
        rep += ", ";
    }
    rep += ")";
    return rep;
  }

  template <std::size_t channel> void setChannelColor(int color) {
    static_assert(channel < channelCount);
    *(begin + channel) = color;
  }

  static constexpr std::size_t getChannelCount() { return channelCount; }
  static constexpr std::size_t getBitResolution() { return bitResolution; }
};

template <class ColorTypeT> class Image {
  using ColorType = Color<ColorTypeT::getChannelCount(), ColorTypeT::getBitResolution()>;
  static constexpr std::size_t channelCount = ColorTypeT::getChannelCount();
  static constexpr std::size_t bitResolution = ColorTypeT::getBitResolution();
  std::size_t width;
  std::size_t height;
  std::vector<int> data;

public:
  Image(std::size_t inWidth, std::size_t inHeight, std::vector<int> inData) : width(inWidth), height(inHeight), data(std::move(inData)) {}

  decltype(auto) GetColor(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) { return ColorType(data.begin() + (row * width + col) * channelCount); }

  std::size_t getWidth() const { return width; }
  std::size_t getHeight() const { return height; }
};

template <class Image> void printImage(Image &image) {
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); ++i) {
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); ++j) {
      std::cout << image.GetColor(i, j).toString() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  std::vector<int> data = {255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255};
  using Color1 = Color<3, 8>;
  using Color2 = Color<1, 8>;
  Image<Color1> i1{3, 3, data};
  Image<Color2> i2{9, 3, data};

  printImage(i1);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  printImage(i2);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  i1.GetColor(0, 0).setChannelColor<1>(128);
  //  i2.GetColor(0, 0).setChannelColor<2>(128); // static_assert fails
  i2.GetColor(0, 0).setChannelColor<0>(128);

  printImage(i1);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  printImage(i2);

  return 0;
}
```

It does not take the resolution into account yet, but that should not be much work.

*EDIT*:
The two classes now don't have a "connection", you can plug in anything that has the methods `getChannelCount` and `getBitResolution`. To enforce this, you can use a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
template<typename T>
concept bool ColorType = requires(T a) {
    { a.getChannelCount() } -> std::size_t { a.getBitResolution() } -> std::size_t;
};
```

And then change the definition of the `Image` class to:

```
template <ColorType ColorTypeT> class Image
```

clang does not support this yet, however, GCC 8 does.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution would let me access the data contained in the array easily as if it was a 2-D matrix. But the requirement I have has something additional to it. In my case the matrix has one more dimension. As each element represent a color, they can have 3 entries (red, green, blue). But it could also be a single entry (in case of grayscale image). I would like to have the ability access the entries as Color instances that are editable. And upon editing the actual data gets changed.

Comment: And I was hoping to represent Color as a separate entity, so that I can say "Color has a DataType, channelCount and bitResolution" And Image is made of a particular Color Type.

Comment: Okay, please see my revised answer. The main method shows how you can manipulate the data through the `Color` class.

Comment: I have revised it again. You can now define a `Color` and pass it as a template parameter to the `Image` class.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on Constraints and concept.